# Issue with accessing jinja python list in javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a python list called "devices" that looks something like this:

```js
[{
  'Version': 'V14E',
  'DeviceID': 'e00fce68281671574f416a8c',
  'TerminationDate': '2050-12-31',
  'Latitude': 31.322139613573903,
  'ActivationDate': '2021-01-04',
  'Longitude': -101.93960164357534,
  'DeviceName': 'Hans_Gruber-1'
}, {
  'Version': 'V14E',
  'DeviceID': 'e00fce68e1265e12e12fa02a',
  'TerminationDate': '2050-12-31',
  'Latitude': 31.32151602493975,
  'ActivationDate': '2021-01-04',
  'Longitude': -101.93948944894449,
  'DeviceName': 'Hans_Gruber-2'
}]
```

In my flask app, I pass this list to my html file by the name "devices_test" using json.dumps() to correctly format the data to be used in java script.

```js
return render_template("json_form.html", 
  devices = devices, components = components, operator = operator, name = site_name, 
  devices_test = json.dumps(devices))
```

Here is me trying to test out an answer I have seen on another post here via the "data" variable:

```js
function update_device_form(strDevice) {

  var data = {
    {
      devices_test | safe
    }
  };

  var device_index = document.getElementById("devices").selectedIndex;

  if (device_index == 0) { //IOW if no device is selected
    document.getElementById("device_id").value = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("device_id").value = '';
  }
```

But I get errors such as "Declaration or statement expected" and "Property assignment expected" and "',' expected". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a seperate js file or javascript is inline in html file.

Comment: @charchit the javascript is in the html file

Comment: Try this `var data = "{{devices_test|safe}}"`

Comment: @charchit that gets rid of the errors but I tried to test it by ```var data = "{{devices_test[0]['DeviceID'] | safe}}";``` and ```document.getElementById("device_id").value = data; ``` but it outputs nothing which then seems like "data" has nothing stored in it. strange...

Answer (score 0):

You can use string to remove the error `var data = "{{devices_test|safe}}"`

Now data is not javascript object, it is a string, you need to use `JSON.parse` and also `replaceAll`.

```
var data = "{{devices_test|safe}}"
var data = data.replaceAll("'",'"') // replace single quote to double
var data = JSON.parse(data)
```

one line

```
var data = JSON.parse("{{devices_test|safe}}".replaceAll("'",'"'))
```

Comment: That seems to break my entire "update_device_form()" function; when that line of code exists, none of the code within the function runs. Any clue as to why this could be breaking my java script?

Comment: any error in console. because it ran prefectly

Comment: no error in console, but when that code is there, nothing under it works.

Comment: With this code `var data = JSON.parse("{{devices_test|safe}}".replaceAll("'",'"'))
        document.getElementById("device_id").value = "foo";` the input box has nothing in it even though it should have "foo". But when I comment your line of code out: `document.getElementById("device_id").value = "foo";` then the input box has "foo" in it like its supposed to. So I figured that your line of code broke the function for some reason.

Comment: this is working fine on my machine. check if devices_test is the correct dict.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: console.log("{{devices_test|safe}}")  and commet the line i gave you, see if it logged the data in console of browser

Comment: The console gives me the error: `json_form:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: update_device_form is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (json_form:26)`, for context the function "update_device_form" is triggered by a change in a html select element. The error only occurs when I try to use jinja, if I do something like console.log("hello") then it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233677/discussion-between-charchit-and-larryyourwaiter).